# JavaScript onmouseout not closing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to mouse over to bring down a menu. The javascript I have works somewhat right. When I mouse over the link or the menu, the menu stays displayed. However, when I mouse out i encounter the problem. My menu div disappears as it should, but the links stay for longer a second longer than the should.

Here is my javascript:

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = null;
var menu       = null;

function showTeams() {
    cancelClose();      // keep showing menu

    if (menu)
        menu = menu.style.visiblity = 'hidden';

    menu = document.getElementById('teams');
    menu.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function close() {
    if (menu) {
        menu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

function closeTeams() {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(close, timeout);
}

function cancelClose() {
    if (closetimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}
```

My CSS:

```
#links {
    width: 533px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 439px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#links li {
    display: inline;
}

#links ul {
    display: inline;
}

#links span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}   

#links a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* alternate browser support */
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    /* normal statement */
    transition:.5s;
}
#links a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #70fc80;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #707070;
}

#teams {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 345px;
    top: 31px;
    border: #5260e5 3px solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;    
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #b4bcfb;
    padding: 2px;
}

#teams a{
    font-size: x-large;
    position: relative;
    color: #5260e5;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none
}

#teams a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 #000;
    background-color: #5260e5;
    display: block;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
            <div id="links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Standings</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onmouseover="showTeams()" onmouseout="closeTeams()">Teams</a>
                        <div id="teams" onmouseover="showTeams()" onmouseout="closeTeams()">
                            <a href="#">Team 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Team 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Team 3</a>
                            <a href="#">Team 5</a>
                            <a href="#">Team 6</a>
                            <a href="#">Team 7</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span></span>
            </div>
```

Any ideas as to why the links are sticking around after the div closes?

Comment: you should probably recreate the situation in a fiddle. it will help us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have transitions on your links:

```
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
/* normal statement */
transition:.5s;
```

This means that there will be a delay in changes. What do you want the transitions for?

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMhjL/) with the transitions removed. You will need to scroll across to teams.

I think you just want to keep the transitions for when you hover. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jMhjL/2/). In that case, move the transitions to hover:

```
#links a:hover {

    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    /* normal statement*/ 
    transition:.5s;
}
```

Comment: the transitions were to have the background for the links fade in